# C++11 Template conditional

Tags: templates, c++11

I want to write template with conditional for only numbers.

```
//in header file
template <typename T,
    typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type 
>
class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo();
};

#include "Foo.inline"
```

And

```
//In inline file
template <
    typename T
>
Foo<T>::Foo()
{
};
```

However, this does not compile. How should be the syntax to have template implementation in separate file?

Comment: @MarcoA. I know, but I dont know what to write there, since second paarmetr in tempalte is nameless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you're defaulting the second template argument to `T` if the first one satisfies `is_arithmetic`. This will work for case 1 but not for case 2

```
template <typename T, 
          typename U = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type>
class Foo {
    public:
        Foo();
};

template <typename T, typename U>
Foo<T, U>::Foo() {
}

struct Obj {};

int main() {
    Foo<int> obj; // Fine
    // Foo<Obj> obj2 // 1) Error - as it should be
    Foo<std::string, Obj> obj3; // 2) Works fine - bad
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c17bc58614d8792d)</kbd>

in order to avoid instantiation if the first type isn't valid for `is_arithmetic` you should use a `static_assert`

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, "T is not an arithmetic type");
    public:
        Foo();
};

template <typename T>
Foo<T>::Foo() {
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/990b03d145886e5f)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for examples and explanation

Answer (score 3):

`std::enable_if` is useful for triggering a substitution failure, so that the compiler can fallback to another overload/specialization.

If you want to verify a template argument, put an appropriate condition in a `static_assert`:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<T>::value,
                  "T must be an arithmetic type");
public:
    Foo();
};

template <typename T>
Foo<T>::Foo()
{
}
```

Or a constraint [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20):

```
template <typename T>
    requires std::is_arithmetic_v<T>
class Foo
{
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The second template parameter should be used in the definition.

```
//in header file
template <typename T,
    typename Enable = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type
>
class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo();
};


//In inline file
template <typename T, typename Enable>
Foo<T, Enable>::Foo()
{
};
```

Comment: But with this, I can write Foo<string, string> foo; and code compiles

Comment: The class Foo has two template parameters. Nothing can prevent you from writing `Foo<string, string>` even if the second parameter is unnamed.

You can hide the second parameter using type alias.